# How to pull data validation from another sheet in Google App Scripts

Tags: javascript, validation, google-apps-script

I'm trying to build a data validation for a cell from a range in a different sheet.  I've tried the below code, and I continue to get this error "".  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function dataValidations(){
  var builder = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Basic Info");
  var invMgmt = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1eGNsJ2iB_IOzcfJe7DyFV_0WhzdQhvW2Lqdzfta2eV4");
  var partners = invMgmt.getSheetByName("Partners and Locations").getRange(2,1,75,1).getValues();
  var partnerRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(partners).build();
  
  var origin = builder.getRange("B4");
  
  origin.setDataValidation(partnerRule);

}
```

Comment: `get this error ""` Did you miss the error info in your description?

Answer (score 3):

In the case of `requireValueInRange(range)`, `range` is the range object. In your script, the values retrieved by `getValues()` is 2 dimensional array. I think that this might be the reason of your issue. So in order to remove this issue, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var partners = invMgmt.getSheetByName("Partners and Locations").getRange(2,1,75,1).getValues();
var partnerRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(partners).build();
```

#### To:

```
var partners = invMgmt.getSheetByName("Partners and Locations").getRange(2,1,75,1).getValues();
var partnerRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(partners.flat()).build();  // Modified
```

#### Note:

- When `SpreadsheetApp.openById("###").getSheetByName("###").getRange(###)` is used for `requireValueInRange`, no error occurs and the retrieved values are the correct from other Spreadsheet. But when I confirmed the data validation in the cell, it is found that `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` is used instead of `SpreadsheetApp.openById("###")`. So in this case, it seems that using `requireValueInList` is suitable.

#### References:

- [requireValueInRange(range)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinrangerange)
- [requireValueInList(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinlistvalues)
- [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: Don't think you can set a `range` as datavalidation from a different spreadsheet(file). Pattern2 will work, If that's the issue

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. From your replying, I noticed an interesting result. When I used `SpreadsheetApp.openById("###").getSheetByName("###").getRange(###)`, no error occurs and the retrieved values are the correct from other Spreadsheet. But when I confirmed the data validation in the cell, it is found that `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` is used instead of `SpreadsheetApp.openById("###")`. How about this in your environment? But I think that this will not expected by OP. So I removed the pattern 1.

Comment: *when I confirmed the data validation in the cell, it is found that* Do you mean, Even if `range`(say `A1:A5`) from `ss2` is set, the active   spreadsheet's sheet's range is used `ss1`'s range (`A1:A5`)is used? That's interesting. If so, I think only A1Notation of a range is retrieved and set regardless of the actual range.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for replying. Sorry. When `SpreadsheetApp.openById("###").getSheetByName("###").getRange(###)` is used for `requireValueInRange`, no error occurs and the retrieved values from `getRange(###)` are the correct. But when I check the data validation which set with `requireValueInRange`, I noticed that `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` is used instead of `SpreadsheetApp.openById("###")`. In this case, the same `getSheetByName("###").getRange(###)` is used.

Comment: @TheMaster Yes. I think that your understanding is correct. At first, I had proposed the pattern 1 because no error occurs.

Comment: *I noticed that SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() is used instead of SpreadsheetApp.openById("###")* I don't think that's  the case. I think `Spreadsheet` is irrelevant. What matters  is the `range` object: If `range` is `A1:A5`, I think that `string` alone is set to datavalidation configuration. It's just a theory.

Comment: @TheMaster In this case, in the internal server, it seems that it uses the information of only sheet and range except for the Spreadsheet. I could know the interesting information by your comment. It might occur the same situation for other methods.

Comment: @TheMaster But, when the error doesn't occur even when `SpreadsheetApp.openById("###")`, this might be not useful for users because users might think that the script works as expecting. I'm worry about this.

Comment: First it is impossible to set a range from a different spreadsheet to the current spreadsheet manually(user interface). Therefore this thought shouldn't even come. If one needs a range from different ``ss``, the natural flow, manually, is to copy the values and use "List of items" (NOT "List from a range"). The fact that it works with `ss.openById()` is indeed a bug, but not a major one, IMO

Comment: @TheMaster Yes. Also I think that Google will not modify this. So I'm worry about it. If I found the same situation for other methods, I would like to summarize them.